# Profiling redis RTT in go

Tags: performance, go, redis

I'm trying to determine best case round-trip times to a redis server. Particularly, I am trying to determine exactly how low I can get the latency on a local instance.

On a technical level, this is pretty easy. However, profiling is always a bit of a dark art, doubly so when network/IPC is involved.

Is this method reasonable?

Here's the numbers I am getting:

```
            localhost:6379:  92.42 µs  # local, bare metal on host tcp loopback 
        /tmp/go/redis.sock:  49.08 µs  # local, bare metal on host unix socket 
            localhost:6380: 276.26 µs  # local, docker networking
```

Which seems in line with my intuition.

```
    package main
    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/go-redis/redis"
        "math"
        "strconv"
        "time"
    )
    
    var ctx = context.Background()
    
    func reduceMin(xs []float64) float64 {
        if len(xs) == 0 {
            return math.NaN()
        }
        if len(xs) == 1 {
            return xs[0]
        }
        best := math.Min(xs[0], xs[1])
        for _, v := range xs {
            best = math.Min(best, v)
        }
        return best
    }
    
    func runProfileN(rdb *redis.Client, N int, tries int) (timePer float64, countErrors int){
        var val string
        totalElapsed := time.Duration(0)
    
        for t := 0; t < tries; t++ {
            start := time.Now()
            for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    
                //err := rdb.Set(ctx, "key", fmt.Sprintf("|%3d|val|%3d|", N, i), 0).Err()
                err := rdb.Set(ctx, "key", fmt.Sprintf("%d", i), 0).Err()
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
    
                val, err = rdb.Get(ctx, "key").Result()
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                i2, err := strconv.Atoi(val)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                if i != i2 {
                    countErrors++
                }
            }
            elapsed := time.Since(start)
            totalElapsed += elapsed
        }
        timePer = float64(totalElapsed.Microseconds()) / float64(N*tries)
        return
    }
    
    func runProfile(redisAddr string) float64 {
        rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
            Addr:     redisAddr,
            Password: "", // no password set
            DB:       0,  // use default DB
        })
        iters := []int{3, 10, 33, 100, 333, 1000, 3333, 10000}
        times := make([]float64, 0)
        tries := 5
        for _, N := range iters {
            timePer, countErrors := runProfileN(rdb, N, tries)
            fmt.Printf("%8d: elapsed: %7.2f µs errors: %d\n", N, timePer, countErrors/tries)
            times = append(times, timePer)
        }
        best := reduceMin(times)
        fmt.Printf("\n %11s best: %7.2f µs \n", " ", best)
        return best
    }
    
    func main() {
        hosts := []string{"localhost:6379", "/tmp/go/redis.sock", "localhost:6380"}
        results := map[string]float64{}
        for _, redisAddr := range hosts {
            fmt.Println("client on ", redisAddr)
            results[redisAddr] = runProfile(redisAddr)
        }
        for _, redisAddr := range hosts {
            fmt.Printf("%30s: %5.2f µs\n", redisAddr, results[redisAddr])
        }
    }
```

Comment: would not be simpler to use pprof and benchmarking ?

Comment: Ah, pprof would be a great idea! I'll give that a spin in a bit.